# ANONYMOUS RESULT :NaN

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;

public class frequency
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String a1, a2, a3;
        double r, l ,c, f;  //r=resistance, l=induction, c=capacitance, f=frequency

        try
        {
            BufferedReader buff=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            System.out.print("Enter the RESISTANCE:");
            a1=buff.readLine();
            r=Double.parseDouble(a1);
            System.out.print("Enter the INDUCTANCE:");
            a2=buff.readLine();
            l=Double.parseDouble(a2);
            System.out.print("Enter the CAPACITANCE:");
            a3=buff.readLine();
            c=Double.parseDouble(a3);

            //for(c=0.01;c<=0.1;c--)
            //{
            f=Math.sqrt((1/l*c) - pow(r,2)/(4*pow(c,2)));
            System.out.print("The FREQUENCY is:"+f);
        }
            //}
        catch(Exception e)
        {}
    }
}
```

The above code is to calculate the frequency. The code is executing properly,but the problem is that the result it is showing is something i don't know. It give show the result as "Nan"

plz explain what is thing & !!

Comment: No need to shout. We can read it quite well.

Comment: What values are you putting in when this happens?

Comment: This code wont compile. where is your **pow** method

Comment: I would advise just doing `r*r` instead of `pow(r,2)`. It won't make *that* much of a difference, but if this was going in a loop, it would make a significant difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input for Math.sqrt() is **NaN** or **less than zero**

From Javadoc for Math.sqrt();

- If the argument is **NaN** or **less than zero**, the result is **NaN**.

I have changed your code to make it work and it is working as long as your input are valid.

```
  import java.io.*;

public class Frequency {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double r, l, c, f;  //r=resistance,l=induction,c=capacitance,f=frequency

        try {
            BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            System.out.print("Enter the RESISTANCE:");
            r = Double.parseDouble(buff.readLine());

            System.out.print("Enter the INDUCTION:");
            l = Double.parseDouble(buff.readLine());

            System.out.print("Enter the CAPACITANCE:");
            c = Double.parseDouble(buff.readLine());

            f = Math.sqrt((1 / l * c) - Math.pow(r, 2) / (4 * Math.pow(c, 2)));
            System.out.println("The FREQUENCY is:" + f);
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

For the below input program quits succesfully

```
run:
Enter the RESISTANCE:10
Enter the INDUCTION:10
Enter the CAPACITANCE:10
The FREQUENCY is:0.8660254037844386
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 12 seconds)
```

For the below input program quits succesfully but prints **NAN** (**Not a number**)

```
run:
Enter the RESISTANCE:0
Enter the INDUCTION:0
Enter the CAPACITANCE:0
The FREQUENCY is:NaN
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 9 seconds)
```

Please provide your inputs.

Comment: TY ITS WRKING ;)BTW R U USING NETBEANS ??

Comment: yeah it is one of my favorite IDEs

Comment: I'M GONNA TRY IT AFTER A FEW , SO MORE QUESTION ARE ON WAY ,BE PREPARED :)

Answer (score 1):

I bet the argument to Math.sqrt() is negative.  When I do `System.out.println(Math.sqrt(-4))` I get `NaN` output.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably dividing by zero somewhere or else `parseDouble` is not parsing correctly. It's also possible that you are trying to find the square root of a negative number, as QuantumMechanic points out.

The easy way to test would be to print out the parsed numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As said before it is Not A Number and it comes from the following line:

```
f=Math.sqrt((1/l*c)-pow(r,2)/(4*pow(c,2)));
```

The value below the square root might become negative (e.g. for large values of `r`). Square root of negative numbers is not defined in the real domain and thus yields NaN.

Note: the formula should actually be `Math.sqrt(1/(l*c)-pow(r,2)/(4*pow(c,2)));`

Comment: WELL HOWARD CODE IS ABSOLUTELY RIGHT ,BECAUSE WHEN I EDIT CODE ACCORDING TO IT GIVES TWO ERRORS MESSAGE FOR BOTH "POW" i.e CANNOT FIND THE SYMBOL ,HOWEVER YOU ARE RIGHT ABOUT SQUARE NEGATIVITY & ITS WORKING NOW THANKS :)

Comment: please use lower-case you are making this site look ugly